Бот не реагирует на сообщения
Написал небольшой код для ТГ бота:
import logging
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.filters import Command

API_TOKEN = 'тут мой токен'

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()

@dp.message(Command("start"))
async def cmd_start(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.reply("Привет! Я бот, который отвечает на 'привет'.")

@dp.message()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    if msg.text.lower() == "привет":
        await msg.reply("Привет!")

async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot, timeout=10, limit=100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


Бот реагирует только на /start. На "привет" никакой реакции нету. В чем ошибка?

Сейчас посидел и понял, что бот воспринимает все сообщения, которые начинаются с "/". Как сделать, чтобы он воспринимал все сообщения?

Через фильтр проверяй @dp.message(F.text == "Привет!") ( только сначала импортируй F через aiogram (from aiogram import  Bot, Dispatcher, F)

Сделал так. types оставил. Все равно не работает
